# How to handle errors DOM in EJS using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am new in Nodejs and EJS.
I want to handle error message on specific action (create, delete, update, get)

I tried to use render with error data. but it replaces existing data from the page.

```
   try {
         const categoryData = await ImageCategory.find({});
         if (categoryData.length > 0) {
             res.render(_BASE_ENDPOINTS.CATEGORY.ALL.FILE, {
                 categoryData: categoryData
             });
         } else {
             res.render(_BASE_ENDPOINTS.CATEGORY.ALL.FILE, {
                 error: {
                  message: "Sorry something went wrong"
                  }
             });
         }

     } catch (error) {
         return res.redirect(_BASE_ENDPOINTS.CATEGORY.ALL.ROUTE);
     }
 }
```

But it breaks the page because it expects **categoryData**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, client and server have to agree on how the request works.  You say you want to change what the server does with the request, but the client doesn't like that.  Well, you have to modify BOTH ends to do what you need.

Comment: The specifics of your question are not very clear.  If you can show the entire request handler on the server AND show and describe what the client code is attempting to accomplish, then we'd have a better chance at offering a specific solution.  As it stands how, you say you have a problem, but don't really describe what the client is trying to accomplish that drives what the server needs to do.